# Do not trigger Jenkins Downstream projects if matches a particular string

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, post-build-event

In a Jenkins job I am running a shell script, on success of which
triggering a downstream project in Postbuild.

I have a problem because my shell scripts gets successful in two
scenarios. For Ex let us consider scenario-A and scenario-B.

If script is successful with scenario-A then it should trigger the
downstream project, but if script is successful with scenario-B then
the job should end and should not trigger downstream script.

tried to match Text and use Text Finder plugin, but it makes build
unstable. I don't want the job status to be Unstable or Failed when
scenario-B passes. I am able to successfully match the strings using
few scripting in Execute shell script plugin, but what should I give
to finish the Jenkins job with success status and avoiding the
downstream project when the string matches.

Execute Shell Plugin Contains

```
cd dir
./myscript
string_name=`cat aaa.log | grep foo`
if [ string_name == "foo" ] then;
   \\Command to aviod downstream project
fi
```

Comment: if you could use a Jenkinsfile and put your conditional in groovy, you could just `build` (trigger the downstream job) when you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me that you'd be better off trying to implement this logic via Build Flows https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin?focusedCommentId=60917290 or Pipeline 2.0 https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

Build flows is probably closer to what you already have right now (and in itself is kind of a bridge in between traditional jobs and Pipeline 2.0).

Your logic would be sth like (groovy code inside a Build Flow or a Pipeline 2.0 Jenkinsfile):

```
if (build('scenario-B-Job'))
   return 
else if build('scenario-A-Job') {
   build('downstream-Job')
}
```

Not sure I get your logic exactly right (you don't mention whether A and B are mutually exclusive or if they can/must run in parallel) but I think you get the idea.